Managing NVM Sets and Endurance groups
I will shortly be setting up a new server with PCIe-attached NVMe solid-state storage, and I am considering what approach to take. It will have a multi-tenant workload (QEMU/KVM virtual machines). I intend to use NVM Namespaces to try to isolate the different tenants. I have also read about NVM Sets (version 2.1, section 3.2.2), and seen hints that they can also be helpful in this scenario (NVMe v1.4 resolves data centre SSD noisy neighbour problems and Enabling NVMe® I/O Determinism @
Scale), but I can't find any tools to manage them. The user guide for the Solidigm Storage Tool (Solidigm is the inheritor of Intel's SSD business) makes no mention of NVM Sets at all, and the open source NVMe-CLI tool only seems to be able to query NVM Sets and Endurance Groups, not manage them. Another presentation that I have found about the subject (Powering the Data Center With NVM Express) says on slide 17: "NVM Set creation/deletion is outside the scope of the current work".
My most basic question is: do NVM Sets and Endurance Groups apply to PCIe-attached NVMe storage at all, or do they only apply to other transports like NVMe-oF or NVMe-TCP? Then, if they are applicable to my situation, how are they managed and are there any summaries of good practices out there? Have I missed something basic, or misunderstood something? I am intending to install AlmaLinux 9 as the base OS, but I would consider non-Windows alternatives if that meant that I would be able to manage the storage more effectively.
Edit: the basic command to manage Endurance Groups and NVM Sets seems to be nvme-capacity-mgmt, but the option values it uses are very low-level. The documentation is not very informative, but looking at the relevant source it can be seen that the command parameters have to be assembled as bytes, words or doublewords. The operation codes are summarised in the NVMe specification (version 2.1, section 5.1.3 and figures 156-158). While this partly answers my original questions, it would still be useful to find some more operator-friendly tooling, and more info on good practice.
